# image uploading in html

Tags: html, jsp

what I want to do is to upload an image to a folder name image in my project,

```
<form>
<input type="file"/>
<input type=""submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

but how can I specify the exact location for my folder,to where I actually want to upload my image.

Comment: I guess you should try to be a bit more precise on waht you intend to do.

Comment: you can use hidden form field to specify a folder location

Comment: i want to upload an image to a particular directory in my pc,how can do that?

Answer (score 1):

HTML Just used For interface In Clint Browser ...

You should Use a Server Programming language Like `php` , `asp.net` &...
Learn more And Read More books ;)

this is a sample code for php file upload:
    
    
    
    
          
http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_file_upload_2.htm

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify where you want the image to be stored in the HTML.

Storing the file in the desired location is done by your backend.